# Android Spinner get NullPointerException

Tags: android, null, spinner

I'm trying to use the following to create a `Spinner`. But I get `NullPointerException` at line

```
        Register.registerlist.setAdapter(spinnernamelist);
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnernamelist= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Register.namelist);
    spinnernamelist.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Register.registerlist=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.showlist);
    Register.registerlist.setAdapter(spinnernamelist);
```

My Logcat output -

```
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3019)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3460)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13955)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3014)
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     ... 11 more
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-22 07:43:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at Picture.Capture.Register.callPictureTake(Register.java:56)
```

Comment: Could you maybe add the stack trace of the NPE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spinnernamelist` obviously isn't null, so `Register.registerlist` has to be null. `findViewById(...)` will return null if it does not find a view with that identifier in the parent layout of the Activity. Make sure the ID you are referencing is indeed in the Activity you are calling it from.

Comment: Is that possible if I want to use an id from another activity?

Comment: Lots of things are possible, though not recommended. With great power comes great responsibility. Passing around `View`s from one Activity to the next has a high potential to cause leaks. The best thing to do is to communicate to the Spinner's Activity what it needs to do and give it the relevant data. `Handler`s are a good way to achieve this, as well as `BroadcastReceiver`s.

Answer (score 2):

Very likely that `Register.registerlist` is null and you get a null pointer exception when you try to run a method on it.

So check if `Register.registerlist` is correctly initialized

Comment: I'm new to android. How to initialize the spinner? Thank you very much

Comment: Check if you have called `setContentView` before you call the `findViewById`? Also check if you have declared the id for the spinner element correctly in the xml file..